# iOS: How do I handle this selector in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

I am trying to convert this Objective c code into swift. However, I do not know how to do this. I've read on how to make a selector work with NSTimer in swift, but not in this situation. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

```
 [apiClient setDidFinishSelector:@selector(method:)];
```

Comment: Do you have access to the definition of the setDidFinishSelector method? if yes have a look at this
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: The `setDidFinishSelector` method is not a native method.  Are you using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're wanting this to be Swift, you'll do

```
apiClient.setDidFinishSelector("method:")
```

and then you just have your method function

```
func method(...) {}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

On a good guess:

```
apiClient.didFinishSelector = Selector("method:")
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is part of the ASIHTTP framework and I believe it is there is no swift version of it.  Either port your code to a new framework or use swifts ability to call objective-c classes (this I have not done myself yet but I know it can be done).